# Play framework Form object for multiple entities

Tags: java, forms, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using Play 2.2.1 and got stuck in a situation. Basically I am working in a `Jobportal` application and I have a situation where the `Jobseeker` needs to fill his/her `skills` (with skill name, skill experience, etc). So for that I have created a separate entity `Skill`.

My problem is that the user have an option of adding multiple skills. So if the user enters only one skill I can simply do:

```
Form<Skill> sk=Form.form(Skill.class).bindRequest();
```

But if the user enters multiple skills how can I retrieve these multiple objects from form? I need something like:

```
Form<List<Skill>> sk=Form.form(Skill.class).bindRequest();
```

Means to retrieve list of entity object from form, the above line is just an explanation to what I want.

I have searched about this topic but didn't get any success. I also know I can simply use `DynamicForm` or `request` but it will give me individual columns, not the entity object.

Is this possible? If yes how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a wrapper class for `Skill` class as follows:

```
public class Skills {

    private List<Skill> skills;

    // setters and getters

}
```

And bind it from request:

```
Form<Skills> skills = Form.form(Skills.class).bindRequest();
```

If you post a json, make it look as follows:

```
{
   "skills": [
      {
         // skill 1
      },
      {
         // skill 2
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for binding multiple objects **Mon Calamari** showed one. You can also just bindFromRequest() without any form with `DynamicForm` and then update given skill(s) yourself.

Anyway... personally I'd do it with jQuery and AJAX definitely, that would be much more *modern* approach, this way you just send request for the `skill` that you want to add/edit/delete and others are untouched, AJAX returns the status of the operation so you can modify page without its reloading and re-rendering whole view each time.